# Windows Store App renaming bug

Tags: windows, rename, store

I have an app on the windows store (windows universal app) and wanted to rename it. So I reserved a new one and changed in visual studio the name as well, now I uploaded the new app packages and after the update on the store I was surprised:
If I use the search bar I see the new appname and if I click at the "magnifying glass" symbol it works as well. But when I go to the details page(with description, screenshots, etc.) of the app, there is the old app name. **I** even **deleted the old app name** in the list of reserved app names. 
So is this a bug from microsoft? Or do I need to adjust something in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to wait for the windows store metadata to update that will take some time.

Make sure though that you changed the name everywhere. I m changing the name of my app as we speak too.
Here is what i did.

1. Reserved a name
2. In visual studio in Package.appxmanifest i changed in Application->Display Name, Visual Assets->Short name, Packaging->Package display name and Packaging->Package Name.
3. Assosiate app with store, where you see the new name that is reserved after you choose the app.
4. Created Packages where you see the new name too.
5. Went to [Live Services site](https://account.live.com/developers/applications/) -> Edit settings ->Basic Info and changed the name there too.

Now I m waiting the release to check if everything is alright.